# WPS change the background and font color in Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, spreadsheet, wps-office

I installed WPS with snap (my OS is Manjaro 20.0.3 "Lysia"), but when I run Spreadsheet the background is black, also the default font color in Spreadsheet and Writer is white color (It is a problem because the background of Writer is white).

I read in the arch linux wiki that [the bad integration with dark themes of KDE is usual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPS_Office#Bad_integration_with_dark_theme_of_KDE_Plasma).

However, I don't know how to execute it with the command that they suggest. I also saw [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/wps-office-sheet-background-color/61688/4), but it's the same. And I don't know how difficult things are having installed it from snap (the path to run this application is not in `bin/et`, `/usr/bin/wps` or something like that).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you - except to try the regular version of WPS Office and to not use the snap. First, uninstall your snap version and then try to download/install the repo (AUR for Manjaro?) version from here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=nd&K=wps+office&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go - snap apps are containerized and that may be the cause of your problems.